# Log user in after signup different subdomain cakephp 3

Tags: php, session, cookies, subdomain, cakephp-3.0

I've got a multi-tenant app where users sign up on:

```
mysite.com
```

After signup I redirect them to their subdomain:

```
newclient.mysite.com
```

I want them to be logged in at `newclient.mysite.com` so I can redirect them to the `newclient.mysite.com/admin/` and have them take the tour of the admin backend.  Note that `newclient.mysite.com` only has access to their subdomain, and sessions/cookies don't persist through other subdomains.

I can't seem to figure this out and have searched through docs.  Any help on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: "_sessions/cookies don't persist through other subdomains_" Why? Making the session cookie apply to `*.mysite.com` seems to be the most simple solution.

Comment: That would allow the new user access to all subdomains. newclient.mysite.com can't have access to newclient2.mysite.com, newclient3.mysite.com, etc.  They only have login access on their own subdomain.  Other thoughts?

Comment: Add some basic, subdomain scoped **[tag:RBAC]**-ish [**authorization**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#authorization) on top. You would want something like that in any case, given that cookies cannot be trusted, just like any other user data, so you have to tie the user and subdomain together at application level anyways.